# telnet localhost smtp gives warning: cannot connect to service

Tags: postfix, smtp, freebsd

I'm trying to setup a mailserver but sending and receiving is not working.
I can connect to a mailbox using pop3 ( trough telnet and mail client )

When do:

```
# telnet localhost smtp
```

the `var/log/maillog` shows:

```
postfix/postscreen[3306]: warning: cannot connect to service private/smtpd: No such file or directory
```

I cannot send anything. Also imap doesn't work and shows the same message 
Do i need to change the location of private/smtpd and if so how?

as for the telnet repose I get:

```
421 4.3.2 All server ports are busy
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

I'm not using chroot
here is my /usr/local/etc/postfix/master.cf [file](http://pastebin.com/iT4kGWPb)

I'm using: freebsd 8.2, postfix 2.8.7

Comment: How did you install postfix?  How did you start postfix?  Does postfix log anything of note when it first starts up?

Comment: Installed via ports? Did you allow the service in `/etc/rc.conf`? If you have not allowed the service, did you run as a `runone` instance? Did you use `/usr/local/etc/rc.d/` to start the services?

Comment: Installed trough ports started using `postfix start`

Comment: also I added postfix_enable to `/etc/rc.conf` and there are no errors shown when I start postfix: `postfix/postfix-script[4569]: starting the Postfix mail system
postfix/master[4570]: daemon started -- version 2.8.7, configuration /usr/local/etc/postfix`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should distinguish between dovecot (pop3/imap) and postfix (smtp). So far you only describe a postfix problem.

Does postfix log any errors on (re)start? A possible cause of problems could be a chroot environment... Verify the paths by running `postfix check`.

**Added:** Check your postfix `main.conf` and `master.conf` (or use `postconf -n`) to look for non-default path names; and check the `queue_directory` (by default `/var/spool/postfix`) which contains the sockets, including `private/smtpd`.
(Dovecot also uses some sockets in the same directory, cf. `/usr/local/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-master.conf`, so that seems to be a secondary error with the same cause.)

Comment: The thing is I get the same error (private/smtpd not found) tying to connect with imap. No errors are shown or postfix restart. 
I'll update my question.
Also I've run `postfix check` which returns no result ( in maillog, and cli )

Answer (score 2):

Check Line

```
smtpd      pass  -       -       -       -       -       smtpd
```

in master.cf file

as guided by http://www.postfix.org/POSTSCREEN_README.html